# Staked Positions in UNISWAP Rewards and Fees

Tags: uniswap

Are the Staked Positions in UNISWAP keep earning the trading fees from the corresponding Pool?  or once it's staked it earns only the staking rewards?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this, the staked Position will keep earning the trading fees portion and the staking rewards.